# Não consigo alterar tipo de coluna -> Objeto Depende da coluna em questão

Tags: sql-server

Preciso modificar o tipo de coluna de uma tabela do cliente, entretanto esta alteração será feita através de um programa escrito em VB.Net e portanto precisa ser feita via comando SQL.

A questão é que ao utilizar o comando:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER COLUMN COLUNA int;
```

Recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
The object 'DF__Tmp_Customer__Coluna__15BB0E23' is dependent on column 'Coluna'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Coluna failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Não consigo de forma alguma, aplicar nenhuma alteração sobre a coluna em questão...

Comment: Isto é SQL Server? Me parece que você tem uma uma referência a esta coluna em algum lugar, tente achar onde é.

Comment: Exato, utilizo sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Pode ter sido criado alguma *constraint* automaticamente pelo DB. Pode ser em *stored procedure*, em *function*. Já tentou com `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT`? Lembre-se de experimentar em dados que possam ser corrompidos se fizer algo errado. talvez tenha que fazer um `DROP CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: Engraçado, que quando eu tento remover a constraint 'DF__Tmp_Customer__Coluna__15BB0E23' o sql me diz que este objeto não existe... mas quando tento alterar a coluna, o sql me diz que essa constraint é dependente do campo.

Comment: Provavelmente porque o DB criou. Pode ser até ter sido criado por causa do *default value*. Já tentou fuçar em todos os objetos do banco de dados procurando por ele? Sabe fazer *queries* nas tabelas de sistema do DB (não nas suas tabelas)?

Comment: Galera, consegui resolver... gerei um script de drop constraint pelo banco e removeu tranquilamente.

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro adicione o script como resposta ou tentar dar umas luzes como resolveu para que as gerações vindouras também saibam como resolver.

Comment: @Omni pronto :D inseri a resposta !

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro favor inserir a sua solução como uma resposta, e não como edição a sua pergunta.

Comment: @Omni Prontinho, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução do Problema :

Script:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[NomeDaConstraint]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NomeDaTabela] DROP CONSTRAINT [NomeDaConstraint]
END
```